# Shortcode inside text widget do not call enqueue style

Tags: shortcode, widgets, wp-enqueue-style, widget-text

I did a plugin who call enqueue style inside a shortcode. But when i add my shortcode in a text widget the enqueue style are not included en the page.

```
wp_enqueue_style('css-rfnb', RFNB_PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'css/rfnb.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

To properly include style you need to do it with `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

With a shortcode, you need to include the file differently as the header has already been send.

One way, Can be to include file in the shortcode. Other way, in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback function can be to scan `the_content`, detect shortcode and include the style like you've done.

If you make your own plugin, you can enqueue the style on each post conditionnaly with [`has_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode)

```
function custom_shortcode_scripts(){
global $post;
if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'custom-shortcode') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_shortcode_scripts');
```

Comment: Hi, i already have this code working on my plugin, but if i put my shortcode in a text widget, It do not call the enqueue files.